# Ошибка Корзины в Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня в браузере где я зашел на админку все работает, а если выйти из админки, добавляется только один продукт в корзину  и при переходе в корзину, пишет что она пустая.

[http://гринфуд.рф/index.php/pizza/](http://%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D1%83%D0%B4.%D1%80%D1%84/index.php/pizza/)

Comment: Да у вас ни один не добавляется, а то что индикатор сверху (в мини-карт) 1 показывает, так это ошибка в его работе. И какие еще ошибки там в плагинах или теме betheme, сказать сложно. Отключайте плагины по одному, смените тему на стандартную. Так сможете нащупать ошибку.

Comment: Вообще-то 1 добавляется, судя по cookie